# Create Draft Email with Python's email.generator package

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I am currently using this code to generate an email with Python:

```py
from email import generator
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def Create_Email():
    msg            = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = 'My Subject'
    msg['To']      = 'test@gmail.com'

    html = """\
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>hello world</body>
    </html>"""

    part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)

    outfile_name = r'C:\Downloads\email_sample.eml'
    with open(outfile_name, 'w') as outfile:
        gen = generator.Generator(outfile)
        gen.flatten(msg)

Create_Email()
```

But when I then open the file with outlook, it appears as an **already-sent** email:

[image]

**How can I change this so that the saved file will be treated as a *draft***, which I can still edit and then send? Like so:

[image]

If `email.generator` cannot do this, I'd be happy to use an alternative package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to avoid having a dependency on Outlook when creating emails/drafts.

The solution I found was very simple in the end; just add this header:

```py
msg.add_header('X-Unsent', '1')
```

It will mark the email as **unsent**, i.e. a **draft**.

Comment: This did not work for me on Mac :/

Answer (score 2):

I created a short mail and it saves to my draft folder. However, you will need the outlook open when you execute the code or it will ask you to provide an outlook profile.

This uses a different module than you did however.

```
import win32com.client as win32

def create_mail(text, subject, recipient, send=True):

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    if send:
        mail.send()
    else:
        mail.save()


create_mail("Hello World!", "Test-Mail", "mail.adresss@gmail.de", send=False)
```