# Python: send multipart message with multiple recievers

Tags: python, pandas, email, multipart, smtplib

I already referred these posts - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899542/python-smtplib-send-message-failing-returning-attributeerror-str-object-ha), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899542/python-smtplib-send-message-failing-returning-attributeerror-str-object-ha). Please don't mark it as duplicate

I am trying to send an email using python smtplib

```
rec_list.append(temp_email_df.iloc[0,4:].to_string(header=False, index=False))
print(rec_list) # this list contains one email id
print(type(rec_list))
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['Subject'] = 'For your review'
message['From'] = 'user1@org.com'
message['To'] = ", ".join(rec_list)
```

My receiver email address comes from pandas dataframe as shown above.

Later, based on the suggestions from stack overflow, I already use `join` operator and put them in the list.

My send_message code looks like below

```
msg_body = message.as_string()
server = SMTP('test.com', 25)
#server.send_message(msg_body,message['From'],message['To']) # doesn't work
server.send_message(message['From'],rec_list,msg_body) # doesn;t work
server.quit() 
rec_list.clear()
```

> I get error message as shown below
>
> ---> 71     server.send_message(message['From'],rec_list,msg_body)
> 72     server.quit()
> 73     rec_list.clear()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py in send_message(self, msg, from_addr,
> to_addrs, mail_options, rcpt_options)
> 942
> 943         self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
> --> 944         resent = msg.get_all('Resent-Date')
> 945         if resent is None:
> 946             header_prefix = ''
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_all'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [send_message()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message), when you should be using [sendmail()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail). The `send_message` method is designed to work with [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message) objects, whereas you are using a [MIMEMultipart](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart) object.

Here is how to send an email with an attachment:

First, start a local debug server (just for testing):

```
$ python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Now send the actual email:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = MIMEMultipart()
message.attach(MIMEText('Test'))
part = MIMEApplication('Attachment', Name='file.txt')
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.txt"'
message.attach(part)

sender = 'myaddress@123.com'
receivers = ['someone@abc.com', 'someone@xyz.com']

message['Subject'] = 'Test Email'
message['From'] = sender
message['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)

with smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 1025) as smtp:
    smtp.sendmail(sender, receivers, message.as_string())
```

This produces the following output on the debug server:

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
b'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============8897222788102853002=="'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Subject: Test Email'
b'From: myaddress@123.com'
b'To: someone@abc.com, someone@xyz.com'
b'X-Peer: ::1'
b''
b'--===============8897222788102853002=='
b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'
b''
b'Test'
b'--===============8897222788102853002=='
b'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name="file.txt"'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
b'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"'
b''
b'QXR0YWNobWVudA=='
b''
b'--===============8897222788102853002==--'
------------ END MESSAGE ------------
```

Comment: thanks for your help. upvoted. will accepted in 10 mins (once SO allows me). So, we can test our mail delivery using debug server? what does the output on debug server say? or how should we interpret your debug server output? am new to smtplib etc. So, not sure

Comment: The output just shows the raw message body, to confirm that the email was correctly sent and received. The format is as per [RFC821 - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc821.html) .

Comment: @TheGreat I'm on Linux, and I don't know anything about Outlook. However, I was able to find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643877/create-draft-email-with-pythons-email-generator-package) which might help.

Comment: Thanks. I referred that post. But do you know what does this line mean `outfile_name = r'C:\Downloads\email_sample.eml'` ? and how is it generated?

Comment: @TheGreat Sorry, not a clue (see my comment above).